# Schedule task on weekends (Saturdays and Sundays) in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cron, command, schedule

I am trying to schedule a task on a specific time in weekends (Saturdays and Sundays) in Laravel. Would this code be correct?

```
$schedule->command('cmd:cmdxy')->weekends()->at( '1:30' )->timezone('My/Timezone')->withoutOverlapping();
```

Comment: Do you have tested it?

Comment: @YaserDarzi I didn't test it yet, because it is not weekend yet.

Comment: Try it and if it doesn't work then come back to Stack Overflow with the problem. Looking at it however, it looks like it should work to me.

Comment: Yes, I will try it, but I would have to wait 1,5 week to see if it works. I was just wondering whether the method "weekends()" means Saturday and Sunday and whether or not I can use the method "at()" with it to apply a time to it

Comment: plz read this article 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling @mbn

Comment: @YaserDarzi It says "->weekends();  Limit the task to weekends". Does this mean Saturday and Sunday? Or once per weekend?

Comment: yes, it means Saturday and Sunday. @mbn